# Text Widget within Appbar leading property - but it's not displaying correctly

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use Appbar with text "Back" button I a using below code but 
"Back" is coming in two line like below, also Appbar title is moving down side.

Ba

ck

Flutter code for same

```
final topAppBar = AppBar(
//    elevation: 0.1,
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(0, 113, 188, 1.0),
    title: Text(
      "MyAppBar",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'Raleway-ExtraBold',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        fontSize: 20.0,
      ),
    ),
    leading: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          "Back",
//          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: "Raleway-Medium",
            fontSize: 14.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),

    ),
  );
```

Is there any thing which I am missing here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use - `FittedBox`  - `fit:` property to adjust leading widget.

```
leading: FittedBox(
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
          child: FlatButton(
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, // add this to remove padding.
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              "Back",
//          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: "Raleway-Medium",
                fontSize: 14.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you. this look perfect but I don't know why font is bigger looks it adopting the AppBar title font style, not I set for Back button. Also padding for left hand side is not working. I will try to figure it out. Thank you :)

Comment: Well done, works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Use `leadingWidth` with enough width.

```
leadingWidth: 80,
leading: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          "Back",
//          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontFamily: "Raleway-Medium",
            fontSize: 14.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```